# Rails: Trying to set a dynamic background picture via CSS but I think Rails is too smart for that

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update the background image of a Rails web application dynamically by fetching it from a Movie model - I have a movie "backdrop" image for most movies, and I want to display the backdrop belonging to a movie if I am on any page for the movie model (show, edit etc), but show a default backdrop (most popular movie that was updated most recently) for all other pages (movie index, home page of web app etc).

Below is the code - the backdrop displays properly (most recently updated most popular movie) when I start the app, it also works if I click through a few movies, but then it's stuck on the most recent backdrop image. I think this might have something to do with the turbolinks-stuff that tries to only reload parts of the page that change maybe?

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    before_action :set_backdrop

    private

    def set_backdrop
        # standard backdrop
        begin
            @backdrop = Movie.where(rating: 10).order(updated_at: :desc).first.backdrop
        rescue
            @backdrop = ''
        end
        if params[:controller] == 'movies'
            if params[:action] != 'index'
                # backdrop: backdrop of current movie
                begin
                    if Movie.find(params[:id]).backdrop.attached?
                        @backdrop = Movie.find(params[:id]).backdrop
                    end
                rescue
                    @backdrop = ''
                end
            end
        end
    end
    ...
```

application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MovieDB</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <style>
      #main {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
          to bottom right,
          rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 20%,
          rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 100%
        ),
        url('<%= url_for(@backdrop) %>');
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  ...
```

(note - backdrop is an image stored through active storage - I don't think that matters here but just for completeness' sake).

Comment: Does it work if you disable turbolinks? (Side note: Your begin/rescue blocks to deal with nil's is not good programming style, as it will lead to very hard to find bugs. Look into the safe navigation opeator.)

Comment: As you suspect, the issue may indeed be related to turbolinks. Suggest you move the style tag that configures the backdrop into the body so that it gets updated when the page changes.

Comment: thanks idmean - will look into the safe navigation operator. and thanks @Les Nightingill - that worked :) ... easy solution, should have thought of that myself but ... sometimes you can't see the simple things any more I guess! :)